# Proftpd specific user configuration from MySQL

Tags: mysql, ftp, proftpd

I have already set up a proftpd server with a MySQL connection.
Everything works fine.

I would like to set specific permissions for each user from the database using (`PathAllowFilter`, `PathDenyFilter`, ...)

The server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS distribution.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where have you looked?  Stackoverflow isn't here to do your job for you.

Comment: Yes, i tried a lot of things without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so easy, there is no single module to do this. But I found a solution for this.

It's not optimal because you have to restart ProFTPd server each time you change MySQL configuration, but it works.

As you have a ProFTPd server that already run with MySQL, i will explain only the part of specific user configuration.

For this solution you need ProFTPd to be compiled with these modules:

- [mod_ifsession](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_ifsession.html) (with this module you will be able to configure `<IfUser>` conditions)
- [mod_conf_sql](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_conf_sql.html) (with this module you will be able to load configuration from MySQL)

To help you with ProFTPd recompilation, you can run this command `proftpd -V` to see how your version is configured. You can found some documentation [here](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Compiling.html).

Once you have compiled your ProFTPd server and it's run, you will have to log on your MySQL server.

If you read [mod_conf_sql](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_conf_sql.html#Usage), they say to create 3 tables `ftpctxt, ftpconf, ftpmap`. We will **not** create these tables unless you want to have global configuration from MySQL.

We will fake the MySQL configuration with "views".

**1. First you add each specific configuration as user column (make sure to have a default value):**

```
ALTER TABLE ftpuser #
ADD PathDenyFilter VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '(\.ftp)|(\.hta)[a-z]+$';`

ALTER TABLE ftpuser 
ADD PathAllowFilter VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '.*$';`
....
```

**2. Create the `conf` view:**

- User's `id` and configuration column are concatenated to make an unique `id`
- User's configuration column is used as `type`
- User's configuration value is used as `info`
- View is an union of selects (for every column an union is required)

  ```
  CREATE VIEW ftpuser_conf AS SELECT concat(ftpuser.id,'-PathDenyFilter') 
  AS id,'PathDenyFilter' AS type,ftpuser.PathDenyFilter AS info from ftpuser 
  UNION 
  SELECT concat(ftpuser.id,'-PathAllowFilter')
  AS id,'PathAllowFilter' AS type, ftpuser.PathAllowFilter AS info 
  from ftpuser;
  ```

**3. Create the `ctxt` view**

- This view is a concatenation of a "Default" row and user's rows ("Default" row has 1 as `id` and user's rows have user's `id` + 1 as `id`.
- Concatenate "userconf-" and user's `id` as `name`
- "IfUser" as `type`
- User's username as `info`

  ```
  CREATE VIEW ftpuser_ctxt AS
    SELECT 1 AS id,NULL AS parent_id, 'default' AS name, 'default' AS type, NULL AS info
    UNION
    SELECT (ftpuser.id + 1) AS id,1 AS parent_id,
           concat('userconf-',ftpuser.userid) AS name,
           'IfUser' AS type,ftpuser.userid AS info
    FRON ftpuser;
  ```

**4. Create the `map` view**

- User's `id` and configuration column are concatenated for `conf_id`
- User's `id` + 1 for `ctxt_id`
- View is an union of selects (for every column an union is required)

  ```
  CREATE VIEW ftpuser_map 
  AS SELECT concat(ftpuser.id,'-PathDenyFilter') 
  AS conf_id,(ftpuser.id + 1) AS ctxt_id 
  from ftpuser 
  union 
  select concat(ftpuser.id,'-PathAllowFilter') 
  AS conf_id,(ftpuser.id + 1) AS ctxt_id 
  from ftpuser;
  ```

**5. Add these lines to your ProFTPd configuration**

```
<IfModule mod_conf_sql.c>
    Include sql://user:password@host/db:database/ctxt:ftpuser_ctxt:id,parent_id,type,info/conf:ftpuser_conf:id,type,info/map:ftpuser_map:conf_id,ctxt_id/base_id=1
</IfModule>
```

Where:

- `user` => your MySQL username
- `password` => your MySQL password
- `host` => your MySQL host
- `database` => your MySQL database

**6. Restart your ProFTPd server**

I hope this will help you. Good luck

Comment: It looks to me to do exactly what I want. I will try this solution.

Comment: It works! It's a great solution thanks! Is there a possibility to change the configuration without restarting the server?

Comment: Glad to see it helped you. No, with this solution you have to restart the server because configuration is loaded once at beginning.